# running tailwind / postcss

Tags: postcss, tailwind-css, stylelint

I'm trying to install Tailwind to practice some basic stuff to learn how this framework works.
I followed every step that Adam Wathan the creator of the framework provided and when it comes to running I face command line error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse.
Also I faced a an error while defining tailwind custom markers

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

first it says unknown at rule @tailwind, then after installing stylelint and following @hasusuf answer
[image: Steps I followed]

another error showing up! 
[image]

and the same command error is still there.

Any help ?

Comment: Which technology you are using like react, angular vue etc?

Comment: used vanilla js, react the same error showing

Comment: I've posted an answer with a basic setup, but re-reading your post I think that the last error you get may be solved just by adding a new empty line at the end of the file

Answer (score 8):

Today I tried installing Tailwind in the most basic way and it worked. I took most information from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/ but if you're not experienced with build tools you can get lost in the last part.

Here are the steps:

#### 1. Create `index.html` and `styles.css` files

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="output.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex container mx-auto justify-center">
        <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-8">
            Button
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the `link` tag is pointing to `output.css` and not `styles.css` (we'll see why in a minute).

**styles.css**

```css
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

#### 2. Initialize npm from the command line and pick the default config

`npm init -y` or `npm init` and answer to all the questions.

#### 3. Install Tailwind from the command line

`npm install tailwindcss`

#### 4. Initialize a basic Tailwind config

`npx tailwindcss init`

#### 5. Build your css file

`npx tailwindcss build styles.css -o output.css`

Here the code you have written in `styles.css` will output in `output.css`.

#### 6. You're done

Open `index.html` from your browser and edit the `html` or `css` file. Note that every change you make on the css file needs a new build (#5).

This is not the better configuration but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio for your detailed answer, I followed your steps and figured that my problem was in package.json file while writing a command to transpile to pure css.

Comment: These are correct steps buy maybe need to improve for best performance. Can you add JIT mode config and -watch steps please.

Comment: @hakiko I happened to be trying to do the same thing when I answered the question, but I haven't followed recent developments like JIT: you can ask a new question if you need more information

Answer (score 3):

***This answer is outdated. Newer versions of tailwind support JIT as default***

Giorgio Tempesta's steps are correct but need to improve for best performance.

Follow below steps for live output to your output css file with **JIT** mode (Just in time). So when you working on your project you don't need to compile source css file manually. Also JIT mode brings dynamic class implementations like `bg-[#abcaaa]`

in your package.json file add these to `scripts` area like

```
 "scripts": {
    "watch-tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i source.css -o output.css -w --minify",
    "build-tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i source.css -o output.css --minify"
  },
```

---

Flag meanings;

```
-i:input file
-o:output file
-w:watch changes
--minify: minify output css file
```

- source.css is your main ang gigantic source css file.
- output.css is your just in time compiled and minified css file.

---

Also your `tailwind.config.css` file should look basically like this

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit", <------------ add this for immediate compile
  purge: ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.js"], <--- give here your source files
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

After saved this settings on your package.json run;

```
npm run watch-tailwind
```

When you run this npm script, tailwind starts to listen changes in your project and output ONLY necessary css declarations to your output.css

It's huge difference. Before you doing above steps your css file is nearly 18MB

After compiling it's nearly 20-30KB

See JIT mode in action: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

This is new era for tailwind.

***Note: JIT mode available on v2.1+***

Comment: Just a note that this update is slightly outdated where **purge:** in the `tailwind.config.css` file has been replaced with **content:** in [TailwindCSS 3.0+ migration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources). It also looks like JIT mode is no longer necessary to have as it's the default.